# Pyparsing infixNotation into a parse tree: Only one operator ending up in tree?

Tags: python, pyparsing, infix-notation

My eventual goal is to apply sql-where-clause-style queries to filter pandas dataframes. Some searching led me to pyparsing's infixNotation method.

I found an example of infix notation here: http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40p%40y%40pyparsing-2.0.2%40examples%40simpleBool.py/15/pyparsing.infixNotation/python#

but that actually processes the notation, and I need to use the tree multiple times on different data. Looking for help with parse trees I found this:
http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/fourFn.py/30154950/fourFn.py

and I took the stack implementation from there. However, it isn't behaving as I expect so I am hoping someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Here is the simplest case I could come up with:

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas, infixNotation, opAssoc

exprStack=[]
def pushFirst( strg, loc, toks ):
    exprStack.append( toks[0] )

def addAnd():
    exprStack.append("and")

varname = Word(alphas).setParseAction( pushFirst )

operators=[("and", 2, opAssoc.LEFT,addAnd)]

whereExpr = infixNotation(varname,operators)

exprStack=[]
teststring = "cheese and crackers and wine"
parsed=whereExpr.parseString(teststring)
for p in exprStack:
    print p
```

What I get from this code is:

```
cheese
crackers
wine
and
```

What I expect to get, from my understanding of how the infix notation method should work, is:

```
cheese
crackers
wine
and
and
```

I also tried running it with "cheese and crackers and wine and whine" but I still only got one "and" in my list.

What am I misunderstanding in using the infixNotation method?

Thank you

Comment: I ended up abandoning the stack approach in the end, and used Paul McGuire's preferred object approach. For anyone looking for SQL-where-type queries applied to pandas dataframes, you can find a version (with only a limited grammar) on github here: [link](https://github.com/moink/askapanda)

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by decorating your parse action with pyparsing's `traceParseAction` diagnostic deccorator.

```
@traceParseAction
def addAnd():
    exprStack.append("and")
```

`traceParseAction` will show the matched source line, the starting location of the matched tokens, and tokens passed to the parse action, and the value that is returned by the parse action:

```
>>entering addAnd(line: 'cheese and crackers and wine', 0, 
                 ([(['cheese', 'and', 'crackers', 'and', 'wine'], {})], {}))
<<leaving addAnd (ret: None)
```

The tokens are a little confusing-looking, since what you are getting is a pyparsing `ParseResults` object, which has both list and dict semantics, so the Python `repr` of the object first shows its list contents, and then its named contents. What looks like a tuple with a list and a dict is really the ParseResults, and in this case, it is a ParseResults whose first element is another ParseResults, and this nested object is the one containing your list of matched tokens.

This is a little easier to see if you add a `tokens` argument to your parse action, and then print out `tokens.dump()`:

```
def addAnd(tokens):
    print(tokens.dump())
    exprStack.append("and")
```

And you'll get the more readable:

```
[['cheese', 'and', 'crackers', 'and', 'wine']]
[0]:
  ['cheese', 'and', 'crackers', 'and', 'wine']
```

You can see that the matched tokens contains not just 'and', but all of the and-ed terms together, so you will need to push as many 'and's onto your exprStack as there are in the matched tokens.

```
def addAnd(tokens):
    exprStack.extend(tokens[0][1::2])
```

With this change, you should now see this as your returned stack:

```
cheese
crackers
wine
and
and
```

Comment: Wow, help from the author of pyparsing himself! Thanks!